# I cannot find the "Resource" type in React-Admin (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I am using the [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/).
My project is working on **TypeScript**.

I am trying to make a Custom Menu, by updating the Layout as follows:

```
const AppLayout = (props: JSX.IntrinsicAttributes) => (
  <Layout
    {...props}
    appBar={AppBar}
    sidebar={Sidebar}
    menu={Menu}
    notification={Notification}
  />
);
```

Unfortunately, I have TypeScript errors in my custom menu implementation. I have ***"Object is of type unknown"*** error on the line `{resources.map((resource) => (`:

```
    import { Theme, useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";
    import LabelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Label";
    import DefaultIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ViewList";
    import React, { FC } from "react";
    import { getResources, MenuItemLink } from "react-admin";
    import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { AppState } from "../../../consts/types";

    interface Props {
      logout: () => void;
      onMenuClick: () => void;
    }

    const Menu: FC<Props> = ({ onMenuClick, logout }) => {
      const isXSmall = useMediaQuery((theme: Theme) =>
        theme.breakpoints.down("xs")
      );
      const open = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);
      const resources = useSelector(getResources);
      return (
        <div>
          {resources.map((resource) => (
            <MenuItemLink
              key={resource.name}
              to={`/${resource.name}`}
              primaryText={
                (resource.options && resource.options.label) || resource.name
              }
              leftIcon={resource.icon ? <resource.icon /> : <DefaultIcon />}
              onClick={onMenuClick}
              sidebarIsOpen={open}
            />
          ))}
          <MenuItemLink
            to="/custom-route"
            primaryText="Miscellaneous"
            leftIcon={<LabelIcon />}
            onClick={onMenuClick}
            sidebarIsOpen={open}
          />
          {isXSmall && logout}
        </div>
      );
    };

export default Menu;
```